# $E[f(X^2)]\geq E[f(X\tilde{X})]$ for $X\sim \tilde{X}$

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

Are there fairly general conditions on $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
E[f(X^2)] \geq E[f(X\tilde{X})]
$$
for all random variables $X$, where $\tilde{X}\sim X$ can be arbitrarily dependent on $X$ but has the same distribution?

For $f=Id$ and $\tilde{X}$ independent of $X$ the inequality becomes $E[X^2]\geq E[X]^2$, which can be proven either via Var X>0 or via Jensen's inequality, neither of which generalizes to the conjectured generalization.

For $f=\log$, the conjectured inequality holds sharply (and trivially) for all $X$.

Unfortunately, I didn't make more progress than that.

Comment: For $f=\mathrm{id}$, how does $E[X\tilde{X}]$ reduce to $E[X]^2$? It seems to me that this happens only when $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ are independent in general.

Comment: Your specialization for f=id makes me feel that you use "arbitrarily dependent" for  "independent" in your first sentence; could you clarify those two words ?

Comment: @SangchulLee I forgot to mention that I consider a further special case there. I'd be absolutely interested in results for the independent case if you have any.

Comment: @Olivier see above

Comment: If it holds for $f$, it fails for $-f$, so you probably want $f$ monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample. Let $X$ be uniformly distributed among $1,2,3,4,5$. Let $\tilde{X}$ have the values $1,5,4,3,2$ in the corresponding situations. Then $$
f(y)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } y\ge 10\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\ \ \implies\ \ 
E[f(X\tilde{X})]=\frac45>\frac25=E[f(X^2)]$$

As a similar but smooth variant,
$$f(y)=\arctan(y-9) \ \ \implies\ 
E[f(X\tilde{X})]=.524>.023=E[f(X^2)]$$